# How to organization relations between component?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular8

It is architecture issue, I will try to explain how I do.

There is `LayerComponent`. It displays layer information.

layer can be edited here by clicking the edit button.

For editing layer there is another `EditLayerComponent` that accepts input layer data.
My issue is, I want to show edit layer component below layer component.
Should it be parent (`LayerComponent`) => Child (`EditLayerComponent`) or they should be placed in the same level?

In this was parent component `LayerComponent` manages `EditLayerComponent`. It is okay.

But trouble arises when I want to show `EditComponent` from another one in application. How to show/hide `EditLayerComponent` then?

Sure, I can use Subject.

So, cases are:

**One:**

```
<LayerComponent>
      <EditLayerComponent [layer]="layer"></EditLayerComponent>
</LayerComponent>
```

**Second:**

In second case I listen event Subject in `EditLayerComponent`, if exists I show edit on form.

Defect is that `EditLayerComponent` will be initialized always.

**Solution:**

Wrap two components:

```
<LayerWrapComponent>
  <LayerComponent></LayerComponent>
  <EditLayerComponent [layer]="layer"></EditLayerComponent>
</LayerWrapComponent>
```

Then listen edit event inside `<LayerWrapComponent>` and pass to `EditLayerComponent`.

Or last way:

Which way to choose?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you are trying to achieve. If it's all about showing one or another tag dapending on some state then your choise is `ngIf` or `ngSwitchCase`.

Comment: I try group components, because it is the same entity. If exist LayerComponent then user shoud edit it (EditLayerComponent). But EditLayerComponent can be call from any component in application.

Comment: Use a Subject, so you can call a method from any component and, with the subscription in the layer component, it will always catch it.